# Windows Crashing

Tags: windows

I am running windows 7 ultimate 64.
I tried installing a program (Nikon camera control pro 2) and right away windows rebooted on me. It got to the point where the mouse displays but before anything else, still black screen, and it remained on this for at least six hours, harddrive flashing every 1.5 seconds. At this point I rebooted and I get to the part where you enter the password and I can enter the password and it continues to load the icons on the desktop and before it seems to be finished it reboots again. If I don’t put in a password and wait on this screen it will also reboot in a few seconds. From a quick look at the blue screen before it reboots I get that iastorv.sys might be the culprit. 
 I tried starting in Safe mode but I get the same thing.  Next I went to an emergency repair disk from about a month ago and booted from it and from its menu I went to the dos prompt and ran chkdsk and it reported nothing bad. 
What are my options?

Comment: Nikon shows unsupported under x64 OS.

Comment: One of your options is to restore from a recent backup.  Or nuke it and reinstall.

Answer (score 3):

Use System Restore to go back to the time before the installation of the Nikon software.

Comment: +1..See method #2...http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/700-system-restore.html

Answer (score 0):

Boot into Windows 7 Repair mode with the windows 7 install disk and use System restore to recover to an earlier snapshot, or even better restore a backup if you have one